# How can I switch from JFrame to java class?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe

I've been trying to figure out how to go from a JFrame to my java class.

This was my code so far: (It only opens the main..which is the JFrame)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar \C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Program\dist\Program.jar");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

The main used to be the class, making it easy for me to use setvislble() for the frame, but now I need it backwards and the main is now the JFrame. I need to know how to open the class file. (Also if anyone knows how to switch besides using CMD that would be great!)

I've tried used this plus a combination of other variations but it won't work.

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Program\dist\Program.jar class"
```

Comment: voting to close - unclear what you are asking

Comment: `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar \C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Program\dist\Program.jar");`  Like fingers scratching a chalk board..  Instead add `Program.jar` to the run-time class path and call the relevant constructor/`main(String[])`..

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Thanks for responding @AndrewThompson. I'm not trying to run or open Program.jar, I'm trying to open a class (e.g. class.java). Opening Program.jar opens the JFrame instead.

Comment: Also @mKorbel my question is how can I hop from a JFrame (with a button for example) and jump into the java class (e.g. something.java). Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: *"..jump into the java class.."*  What does that mean?  Is `something.class` a class that extends `Frame` or `Window` or `JPanel`?  Does it provide text output?  Is it a class that can be run through the command line?  I agree with @mKorbel that this question is unclear.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I apologize. Imagine pressing a button, then that frame disappears and it loads a class. This class is run through the command line, it has no GUI. The class extends Frame, but so far it collects most of it's information through a textfile (which has no relevance to this question). I'm asking how can I open the class which is based on command line.

Comment: *"I'm asking how can I open the class which is based on command line."*  So the output as produced by something like `System.out.println(..)`?  That would make it a poor candidate for getting the same information in a GUI.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm basically getting the user to input information in the GUI, then sending that information into a textfile. The class reads the textfile, gets the information and does its things. And the main reason I'm not using the GUI for everything is because a JFrame button, if my understanding is correct, does not handle infinite loops well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JFrame button, if my understanding is correct, does not handle infinite loops well.

The idea is not to block the EDT, but there are certainly **correct ways** to repeat an action (until told otherwise) in Swing, as well as ways to do long running tasks.  Here is some advice I commonly give:

> Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

But back to the matter at hand..

> ..getting the user to input information in the GUI, then sending that information into a text file. The class reads the text file, gets the information and does its things..

OK that is 10 different kinds of wrong.

Let's say the GUI is called `GUI.class`, the other class is called `Worker.class`.

### `Worker.class`

This class might have a no-args constructor as well as a constructor that accepts an `InputStream` (for the text file, if it is finally needed).

The `Worker` class might have a `main(String[])` that creates an instance of a `Worker` object.  It might use either:

1. An `InputStream` for the constructor of the `Worker`, from which it would configure the fields needed for the work to be done.
2. A no-args constructor for the `Worker` instance, then use **setter methods** for configuring it.  (Maybe prompting the user through the command line to supply the information.)

Once the `main` has done that, call `execute()` on the `Worker` instance and call **getter methods** for the results, then write the results to `System.out`.

### `GUI.class`

The GUI can also use a `Worker` instance.  It would probably use the no-args variant then bind the setter methods to the input controls in the GUI.  Once the user clicks the <kbd>Execute</kbd> button, `execute()` the process, then query the getter methods to display the results to the user (still in the GUI).

Comment: Although this helped me with the exchanging of results from GUI to class, I still need to know how I can open the .class file from the JButton? If you think it's impossible to open the .class file here is some specifics if you have any idea how to make my idea work in the GUI entirely.. The "infinite loop" I was talking about is this: Once the data is stored, the program reads a website for a specific word, if that word is not found it will keep checking until it does. Is there a way to incorporate this idea into your "not blocking EDT" method?

Comment: *"I still need to know how I can open the .class file from the JButton?"*  Stop thinking 'open the class file' and start thinking 'create an instance of the class to use'.  If the class is on the run-time class-path of the app., do like I described above.  Create an instance of the class, configure it and use it.  I don't understand what part of that you are having trouble with..

Comment: *"..if that word is not found it will keep checking until it does. Is there a way to incorporate this idea into your "not blocking EDT" method?"*  If you had read the Concurrency in Swing article I linked to, you'd already know the answer to that.  Don't expect to be spoon-fed.

Comment: After reading your comments, the article, and a few other articles I figured it out! SwingWorker did the job. Thanks a lot for the patience and help!

Comment: *"..I figured it out!"*  Congrats!  Glad you got it sorted.  :)